# Count occurrences of string in logfile in last 5 minutes in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have log file containing logs like this:

```
[Oct 13 09:28:15] WARNING.... Today is good day...
[Oct 13 09:28:15] Info... Tommorow will be...
[Oct 13 09:28:15] WARNING.... Yesterday was...
```

I need shell command to count occurrences of certain string in last 5 minutes.
I have tried this:

```
$(awk -v d1="$(date --date="-5 min" "+%b %_d %H:%M:%S")" -v d2="$(date "+%b %_d %H:%M:%S")" '$0 > d1 && $0 < d2 || $0 ~ d2' "$1" |
grep -ci "$2")
```

and calling script like this: `sh ${script} /var/log/message "day"` but it does not work

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your tried code in your question which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: That is fine, there is nothing right or wrong, we all are here to learn. So just add your tried code(**in your Question**) as your efforts and people could try to help you here, cheers.

Comment: what is `last 5 minutes` based on? the time at which the script is run, minus 5 minutes? or the last timestamp in the file, minus 5 minutes? for the former the output would be `0` if the script is run on 13 Oct @ 14:00; for the latter the output would be `3` for all entries between 13 Oct 09:23:15 and 13 Oct 09:28:15

Comment: when searching for `day`, should this match on `Today` or do you only want exact word matches? in your sample code you have `grep -ci` where `-c` says to count number of lines, but in the description you mention wanting the count of strings; for the 1st line in the log file `day` will match on `Today` and `day` ... does this count as `1` or `2` ... and if the answer is `1` then why - because you want to count lines or because you don't want to match on `Today`?

Answer (score 3):

Your immediate problem is that you are comparing dates in random string format. To Awk (and your computer generally) a string which starts with "Dec" is "less than" a string which starts with "Oct" (this is what `date +%b` produces). Generally, you would want both your log files and your programs to use dates in some standard computer-readable format, usually ISO 8601.

Unfortunately, though, sometimes you can't control that, and need to adapt your code accordingly. The solution then is to normalize the dates before comparing them.

```
awk -v d1=$(date -d "-5 min" +"%F-%T") -v d2=$(date +"%F-%T") '
    BEGIN { split("Jan:Feb:Mar:Apr:May:Jun:Jul:Aug:Sep:Oct:Nov:Dec", m, ":")
        for (i=1; i<=12; ++i) mon["[" m[i]] = i }
      { timestamp = substr(d1, 1, 5) mon[$1] "-" $2 "-" $3 }
      timestamp > d1 && timestamp <= d2' "$1" | grep -ci "$2
```

This **will not work** across New Year boundaries, but should hopefully at least help get you started in the right direction. (I suppose you could check if the year in `d2` is different, and then check if the month in `$1` is January, and then add 1 to the year from `d1` in `timestamp`; but I leave this as an exercise for the desperate. This still won't work across longer periods of time, but the OP calls for a maximum period of 5 minutes, so the log can't straddle multiple years. Or if it does, you have a more fundamental problem.)

Perhaps note as well that `date -d` is a GNU extension which is not portable to POSIX (so this will not work e.g. on MacOS without modifications).

(Also, for production use, I would refactor the `grep -ci` into the Awk script; see also [useless use of `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep).)

Finally, the command substitution `$(...)` around your entire command line is wrong; this would instruct your shell to use the output from Awk and run it as a command.